# Access 2003 VBA OnNavigation event?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2003 VBA forms, what event is fired when the user changes the record the form is looking at?

(ie: pressing the arrow buttons at the bottom left of the form)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use Current.

Comment: Perfect, thought it would be simple to do.

Comment: That's the record arrival event. There is no record departure event.